# Extended class don't need same arguments

Tags: php, interface, abstract-class

I have an issue with the way my classes are implemented
I have an abstract class which implements an interface :

```
interface DriverInterface {

   public function __construct(
      array $tableGateway,
      Sql $sql,
      $dbName,
   );

   public function process();

   public function setIdentiteService(IdentiteService $service);
   public function setPhotoService(PhotoService $service);
   public function setDocumentService(DocumentService $service);
   public function setLotService(LotService $lotService);
}
```

Abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractDriverMigration implements DriverInterface {

   protected $tableGateway;
   protected $sql;
   protected $dbName; 

   public function __construct(array $tableGateway, Sql $sql, $dbName)
   {
      $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
      $this->sql = $sql;
      $this->dbName = $dbName;
   }

   abstract public function process();

   public function setIdentiteService(IdentiteService $service) {}
   public function setPhotoService(PhotoService $service) {}
   public function setDocumentService(DocumentService $service) {}
   public function setLotService(LotService $service) {}
}
```

Then I call the classes which extends the abstract class programmatically :

```
$className = 'Migration\\Driver\\' . str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $class)));
$driver = new $className(...);
```

But the thing is that, for some classes, but not all, I need to pass services with the 'setXService' functions that I override from the abstract class, and I end up testing which class it is to pass the services. And I don't like doing that.

```
if ($class == 'user' ) {
   $driver->setLotService($service)
}
```

And I don't want to pass the services to all the classes, since some of them don't need them.

Comment: I didn't know an abstract class could _extend_ an interface..., shouldn't that be _implements_? And why do you use both an interface and an abstract class; why not just put everything in the abstract class?

Comment: Indeed, an interface should be implemented and not extended. I edited it thanks. Well the abstract class implements an interface just like a normal class would do. Then the extended class would also implements the interface.